# How to filter doctrine queries systematically with dynamic variable in symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, filter, doctrine

I want to systematically filter doctrine queries so I don't have to specify some data any time I use a repository.

For instance, I have one single database where entities are binded to clients. I want to be able to retrieve my entities whether I'm this or that client transparently like:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('ns:Entity')->findAll();
```

So I used a filter which I would like to bo something like:

```
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
{
    $id = $this->get('session')->get('current_client_id');

    return sprintf("$targetTableAlias.client_id=%d", $id);
}
```

The problem is, filter operate at sql level, so it's not container aware, so I can't access session or services (which may be wrong).

Any idea how to deal with dynamic filtering ?

I tried with custom repositories, but same problem happens, plus I'd have to duplicate functions for every entity.

[EDIT]

You can resolve this passing a parameter to the filter:

```
$filter = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getFilters()->enable('my_filter');
$filter->setParameter('current_fair_id', $currentFair->getId());
```

Then all that's left to do is getting the parameter within the addFilterConstraint method of your QueryFilter inherited class:

```
$value = $this->getParameter('current_fair_id');
```

Comment: Where did you define `addFilterConstraint` function, is it in entity? Do you call it through controller?

Comment: @Javad It is defined as a filter in the config.yml file e.g:  filters{ query{ class: Path\QueryFilter, enabled: true }}

It's impossible to inject dependency to this filter. Options are listed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't show you a working example for **symfony2** but in **zf2** here:
[Setup Doctrine 2 filters in Zend Framework 2](http://www.daredevel.com/setup-doctrine2-filters-in-zend-framework-2/)

Anyway this should be portable to **symfony2** by finding the place in your code where you *enable* the filter. This is the place where you can also set / add parameters like you *session_id*:

```
$id = $this->get('session')->get('current_client_id');
$filter = $entityManager->getFilters()->enable('your_filter_class_name');
$filter->setParameter('current_client_id', $id);
```

[Please see Doctrine docs here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html#example-filter-class):

> Parameters for the query should be set on the filter object by SQLFilter#setParameter(). Only parameters set via this function can be used in filters. The SQLFilter#getParameter() function takes care of the proper quoting of parameters.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. Setting parameters then getting them with $filter->getParameter() works like a charm!

Comment: Good to see that frameworks and ORMs in the PHP world are finally starting to talk a common - or at least portable - language! :) Maybe you could post a short code snippet (edit question) for the symfony users.